# an AngularJS web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to implement an AngularJS web application. now I want to attach an average time or countdown timer . I want to have something working quickly. (quiz and question part is already implemented only )

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site to give out coding tasks, it is there to help you if  you have specific problems. Show us what you have tried!

Comment: 'I want to have something working quickly' << This kind of requests will quickly drive away, most of the people who would normally help you. This is a site which people help each-other, not do each-other's tasks. Just a friendly advice :)

Comment: I'm new on Stack Overflow so if i have made any mistake please don't hold it against me. I'm not here to complete my tas, If someone can light my way, it would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

i had created a countdown timer for somewhat similar purpose [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/t106zLNk1QMmgnL9kvmu) , thought it would need some modification to be a perfect fit for your exact need

1. Initially you see instruction page, where timer is initialized to 2 hours.
2. Then move to questions 1, where timer starts
3. from question 1 you can go to help page, where the timer pauses
4. then you move back to question 2, where timer resumes...

as per your requirement you can use service like below :

1. start init it on first page

   ```
   app.controller('view1Ctrl', function($scope, $csCountdown){
     $csCountdown.init(2 * 3600); // 2 hours
     $scope.countdown = $csCountdown.data;
   })
   ```
2. start the counter on second page

   ```
   app.controller('view2Ctrl', function($scope, $csCountdown){
     $csCountdown.start();
     $scope.countdown = $csCountdown.data;
   })
   ```

you can display the value on any page using `countdown.stringValue`

```
<h1>Time : {{countdown.stringValue}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use setInterval to count down a variable from 100 every second. If the variable hits 0 perform an action like redirecting the user to the next question.

```
var countDown = 100;
setInterval(function(){
  countDown--;
  if (0 == countDown) {
    alert('Your time is up. Here is your next question');
    // Provide next question
    countDown = 100;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but the code should be in angular.js only